# Tornado- how to call a handler in another function

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, websocket, tornado

I am currently trying to use Tornado's web-socket handlers to update a dashboard every time a certain function is called. here is the handler:

```
class WebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []
    def open(self):
        logging.info("WEBSOCKET OPEN")
        WebSocketHandler.clients.append(self)
    def on_message(self, message):
        logging.info("message from websocket recieved")
        self.write_message("WebSocket connected")
    def on_close(self):
        logging.info("WEBSOCKET closed")
```

and here is the client-side script which connects the WebSocket on load:

```
  function WebSocketTest()
{ var ws = 0;
   ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8008/WEB");
   ws.onopen = function()
    {
    ws.send("initial connect")
    }

  ws.onmessage = function (evt)
  {
    console.log(evt.data)
  };

  ws.onclose = function()
  {
    console.log("closed ");
  };
}
```

The websockets connect sucessfully.

i need to call `write_message` from `WebSocketHandler` but i'm very confused what the instance of it is? the error i keep running into is that `self isn't defined` but im not sure what self is exactly? i know that `WebSocketHandler` gets run whenever the client tries to load `^/WEB$`

EDIT: here is my `server.py` file, i need to call write_message right after the `spawn callback` call in `itercheckers`

```
class Server():



@classmethod
def run(cls):
    options.parse_command_line()
    # Start web
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    jinja2loader = Jinja2Loader(template_path)
    kwargs = dict(
        template_loader=jinja2loader,
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
        debug=True,
        login_url="/auth/login",
        cookie_secret="dn470h8yedWF9j61BJH2aY701i6UUexx"
    )
    app = web.Application(handlers, **kwargs).listen(
        configuration['server']['port'],)

    # Reset events
    @gen.coroutine
    def reset(parent=None):
        if parent is None:
            parent = configuration
        # Reset event happyness
        yield events.reset_happy(parent)
        # Read last status
        data = yield events.get(parent)
        # Read and set happy from the last status
        happy = (data or {}).get('status', events.STATUS_OK) \
            in events.HAPPY
        yield events.set_happy(parent, happy)
        # Iterate sub-events
        for event in parent['events']:
            yield reset(event)

    ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(reset)



    # Start checkers
    def itercheckers(parent):
        index = 0
        for event in parent.get('events', []):
            if 'checker' in event:
                checker = event['checker']
                p, m = checker['class'].rsplit('.', 1)
                ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(
                    getattr(importlib.import_module(p), m)(
                        event=event,
                        frequency=checker.get('frequency', 1),
                        params=checker['params']
                    ).run)
            index += 1
            itercheckers(event)
    itercheckers(configuration)



    # Start alerts
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(alerts.reset)
    for alert in configuration['alerts']:
        p, m = alert['class'].rsplit('.', 1)
        ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(
            getattr(importlib.import_module(p), m)(
                alert=alert
            ).run
        )

    # Start loop
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: how do you access it ? you don't go to ws://localhost:8000/ws ? you must make html page with the js and open console on that page to see what's the output

Comment: No i do. the link to access WebSocketHandler is "/WEB".  `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8008/WEB");` connects me

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, `self` keyword is pointed to current websocket client that is handled in the moment. To use tornado websockets you must initialize tornado app

```
app = web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler), #tells it to redirect ws:// to websocket handler
#Choose different names from defaults because of clarity
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(5000) #listen on what port
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Then you must have `WSHandler` class you're pointing websockets trafic to

```
class WSHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    #crossdomain connections allowed
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
    #when websocket connection is opened
    def open(self):
       print("Client connected ")

    def on_close(self):
       print("Client disconnected")

    def on_message(self,message):
       self.write_message(message) #echo back whatever client sent you
```

So complete app would look like

```
from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop
clients = [] 

#whenever you want to broadcast to all connected call this function
def broadcast_message(msg):
    global clients 
    for client in clients:
        client.write_message(msg)

class WSHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    #crossdomain connections allowed
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
    #when websocket connection is opened
    def open(self):
       #here you can add clients to your client list if you want
       clients.append(self)
       print("Client connected ")

    def on_close(self):
       clients.remove(self)
       print("Client disconnected")

    def on_message(self,message):
       self.write_message(message) #echo back whatever client sent you

app = web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler), #tells it to redirect ws:// to websocket handler
#Choose different names from defaults because of clarity
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(5000) #listen on what port
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And now to connect to it with js

```
function WebSocketTest()
{ 
   var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/ws");
    ws.onopen = function()
    {
       ws.send("initial connect")
    }

    ws.onmessage = function (evt)
    {
       console.log(evt.data) 
    };

    ws.onclose = function()
    {
       console.log("closed ");
    };
}
```

I haven't tested it but should work

Comment: sorry I should have included it but I have a `server.py` file where I create `web.Application` and pass a list of handlers. I can definitely connect my clients to the server. What I'm trying to figure out is how to send data from the server to the client based on a server-side event.

Comment: You want to send to specific client or all clients

Comment: all clients. it's a status-dashboard that i need to update whenever a specific function is called

Comment: Ok I'll edit server code in just a second .. now you just call the broadcast_message, with message argument `broadcast_message("ABC")` and it will send that message to all connected clients, but you can call it only after it's declaration because python is interpreted it can't see ahead